Identification of the spectrum color of a coded video signal
I have two encoded video signals (MPEG and H.263). In each file, I have information about the frames of the video.
I calculated the autocorrelation and then did the Fourier transform to find and plot the power spectral density as shown in the image below:

Given this result, I'm trying to figure out what is the color of the spectrum.
Ex: 1/f⁰ = white
1/f¹ = pink
1/f² = brown
I am unable to identify this characteristic due to the signal decay. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's not possible to identify the color of the spectrum for this signal.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Are you looking at the bitstream of these codecs? Using some packetization?
